# SQL SERVER Convert Function Not Working Varchar to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use the convert function to convert dates stored as a varchar(12) into a date and the values don't change when returned.

I have tried both CAST and CONVERT (Varchar(10), COL_Name, 126) and neither one modifies the values into the date I am looking to return. I think the problem may be the 3rd party service we use stores the dates both in m(m)/d(d)/yyyy and yyyymmdd00 format.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), SENIORITY, 126) SENIORITY from #TEMP1

SELECT CAST(SENIORITY AS DATE) SENIORITY from #TEMP1
```

Returns as follows:

```
SENIORITY
8/14/2017
2017082200
2018031500
04/25/2011
04/25/2011
7/18/2011
06/20/2011
9/12/2011
7/17/2011
01/16/2012
```

I'm expecting:

```
SENIORITY
2017-08-14
2017-08-22
2018-03-15
2011-04-25
etc.
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of the yyyymmdd00 storage that it is sometimes doing but I don't know how to modify the query to account for and convert properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have 2 `SELECT` statements in your example, but you have only one in your output. If the **first** `SELECT` statement is returning data like `'8/14/2017'` **and** `'2017082200'` you're mistaken about the data type of your column  `SENIORITY`; it's not a `date`, it's a `varchar`. Converting a `varchar` to a `varchar` achieves nothing.

Comment: Those are the two different selects I've tried.  I know the column is a varchar, I'm trying to convert it to date.

Comment: Then you would need to use `CONVERT(date...`. `CONVERT(varchar...` converts the value **to** a `varchar`.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select (case when sen9ority like '%/%/%'
             then convert(date, seniority, 101)
             else convert(date, left(seniority, 8))
        end)
```

Or, you could use `try_convert()` and `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, seniority, 101),
                try_convert(date, left(seniority, 8))
               )
```

Comment: @OneSQLUser the second option was just missing a comma.  This has been corrected.   Be sure to show your appreciation by ACCEPTING answers.

Comment: @OneSQLUser, it's great that you found your answer! Please accept this as the correct answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left, which will turn green and become visible to the rest of us when you click it. It lets other users know the question has a working answer, and also rewards you and the person who posted the answer with some reputation points.